# My append command doesn't work python

Tags: python, append

Here is my code:

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
print("here are the letters you already searched",letters)
letter = input("please enter a letter")
print(letter)
letters = letters.append(letter)
```

It won't append it to the list. I also tried this:

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
print("here are the letters you already searched",letters)
letter = input("please enter a letter")
print(letter)
letters.append(letter)
```

Comment: what is wrong with the second one?

Comment: i don't know but it wan't append it

Comment: The first example here won't work because append returns None (it appends "in-place"). The second example works fine (just tested it). Maybe you could share more of the code or tell us exactly what you want to achieve if something isn't behaving as expected? (Edited to clarify return value of append).

Comment: `.append(..)` works **inplace**. So you should write `letters.append(letter)`, not ``letters = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example won't work because you're using `letters = letters.append` which with `=` is trying to reassign the letters variable, your second example is the correct one, but...

...what you might be looking for is a loop so you can continuously enter letters, `while True:` is one way of creating a loop:

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
while True:
    print("here are the letters you already searched",letters)
    letter = input("please enter a letter: ")
    letters.append(letter)
```

to have an option to break out of the loop use `break`

```
letters = ['a','b','c']
while True:
    print("here are the letters you already searched",letters)
    print("type '_done_' to finish")
    letter = input("please enter a letter: ")
    if letter == "_done_":
        break
    letters.append(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `raw_input` (with your second example) instead:

```
letter = raw_input("please enter a letter")
letters.append(letter)
```

You were probably entering a letter like `d` when asked for `input` when  it actually should have been `"d"` (which will append properly). `raw_input` will always convert your letter to a string, so you may enter it like `d`. Please read over the difference:

> `input()` interprets and evaluates the input which means that if the user enters an integer, an integer will be returned, if user enters string, string is returned.
>
> `raw_input()` takes exactly what the user typed and passes it back as a string. It doesn’t interpret the user input. Even an integer value of 10 is entered or a list is entered its type will be of string only.

[Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-raw_input-and-input-in-Python)